# Typescript - Unable to get 'import' statement to function

Tags: typescript

Using typescript, I am attempting to get 'modules' and 'imports' and such to work, and am having a bit of a rough time. I was asked to make an example of my problem, so here it is;

I use namespace style declaration to try and organize various parts of the project, this is just how I work the best and it helps me keep things free of a clutter that bothers me, so each typescript page starts with the namespace, and then it exports the corresponding class.

#### `/app_content/scripts/admin/models/Item.ts`

```
module website.admin.models {
   export class Item {
      // properties, etc
   }
}
```

#### `/app_content/scripts/admin/ui/Component.ts`

```
module website.admin.ui {
   export class Component {
      // properties, etc
   }
}
```

Then I will attempt to use one of these in a different file, as I have seen in many, many tutorials;

#### `/app_content/scripts/admin/views/ItemView.ts`

```
import component = module('website.admin.ui.Component');
import item = module('website.admin.models.Item');

module website.admin.views {
   export class ItemView {
       // try to use stuff, do other stuff, etc.
   }
}
```

However, I get the error `Module cannot be aliased to a non-module type`. I have yet to get any of these `imports` working at all - let alone how I want them. Is there anything that can be done?

I have tried this with Visual Studio set to use both CommonJS and AMD style and such, in the properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Drop Module Declarations

The first step is to remove all your module declarations...

```
module website.admin.models {
```

All of those can go because you are using External Modules, so `a file === a module`. The entire contents of the file is treated as if it were a module. External Modules never dirty the global namespace in any way, which is cool.

## Importing

So without the module declarations, what is your module name? It is the path to the module, so now when you import, you do it like this:

```
import component = require('./app_content/scripts/admin/ui/Component');
```

Important note - don't add the file extension.

Important additional note - use `require` instead of `module` (this changed in the TypeScript specification).

## Full Example

So your code now looks like this...

`/app_content/scripts/admin/models/Item.ts`

```
export class Item {
    // properties, etc
}
```

`/app_content/scripts/admin/ui/Component.ts`

```
export class Component {
    // properties, etc
}
```

`/app_content/scripts/admin/views/ItemView.ts`

```
import Component = require('./app_content/scripts/admin/ui/Component');
import Item = require('./app_content/scripts/admin/models/Item');

export class ItemView {
    example() {
        var component = new Component.Component();
    }
    // try to use stuff, do other stuff, etc.
}
```

## Exporting Something Else

Additional cool feature alert! Once you have the above working, try this...

If you don't like this repetition...

```
var component = new Component.Component();
```

If you only have one class in `Component.ts`, you can export the class in place of the module like this...

```
class Component {
    // properties, etc
}

export = Component;
```

Now you can use the much prettier:

```
var component = new Component();
```

In your `ItemView.ts` file.

## Runtime

To actually kick this all off in a web browser, you just include [require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) and tell it your top level program file (usually `app.ts`, for example). It will load `app.ts`, then when it encounters a `require` it will load that module and so on.

```
<script data-main="/scripts/app" src="/scripts/require.js"></script>
```

Again, leave out the file extension in the `data-main` attribute.

Comment: Is there a way to set up a 'base' url so that I can omit the `./app_content/scripts/` part? I seem to recall that requirejs had something like that.

Comment: I believe you can do it in the require.js config - but I'll be honest and say that it is actually easier to use the full paths in TypeScript - you only need them in the import statements. This is because the TypeScript language service won't know about the require.js config - so it will complain about the short path.